# Cannot change the localization

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I implemented the localization in my app following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-2.1) documentation and actually I got a problem when I change the language through the select box, infact when I select english the application still have the italian language.

When I change the language seems that the app execute a refresh but the language is always setted to italian, the weird thing is that if I add a query string in the url which have this `http://localhost:5000/?culture=en` then the application will run in english and the selected item in the select will be setted to english too.

Inside the `ConfigureService` method I added the following:

```
services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");

services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
{
    var supportedCultures = new[]
   {
       new CultureInfo("it-IT"),
       new CultureInfo("en")
   };

   options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("it-IT");

   options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;

   options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;

   options.RequestCultureProviders = new List<IRequestCultureProvider>
   {
       new QueryStringRequestCultureProvider(),
       new CookieRequestCultureProvider()
   };
});
```

so as you can see I have only two languages: `english, italian` both of them have the `.resx` files available inside the folder `Resources`, specifically, I added the file for each `Controller` in the properly folder:

[image]

then in the `Configure` method I added this: `app.UseRequestLocalization();` before `UseMvc` as indicated in the documentation.

Then I created a `View` inside `Shared` folder called `_SelectLanguagePartial.cshtml`, this `View` contains the following content:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Options

@inject IViewLocalizer Localizer
@inject IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions> LocOptions

@{
    var requestCulture = Context.Features.Get<IRequestCultureFeature>();
    var cultureItems = LocOptions.Value.SupportedUICultures
        .Select(c => new SelectListItem { Value = c.Name, Text = c.DisplayName })
        .ToList();
    var returnUrl = string.IsNullOrEmpty(Context.Request.Path) ? "~/" : $"~{Context.Request.Path.Value}";
}

<div title="@Localizer["Request culture provider:"] @requestCulture?.Provider?.GetType().Name">
    <form id="selectLanguage" asp-controller="Language"
          asp-action="SetLanguage" asp-route-returnUrl="@returnUrl"
          method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
        <label asp-for="@requestCulture.RequestCulture.UICulture.Name">@Localizer["Language:"]</label>
        <select name="culture" onchange="this.form.submit();"
                asp-for="@requestCulture.RequestCulture.UICulture.Name"
                asp-items="cultureItems"></select>
    </form>
</div>
```

I load this `View` in the `_Layout.cshtml` footer which contains the basic `html` of the site: `@await Html.PartialAsync("_SelectLanguagePartial")`.

Now I also created another controller called `LanguageController` which contains the method `SetLanguage` and it's called each time I select an item from the `select` available in the `footer`

```
public class LanguageController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult SetLanguage(string culture, string returnUrl)
    {
        Response.Cookies.Append(
            CookieRequestCultureProvider.DefaultCookieName,
            CookieRequestCultureProvider.MakeCookieValue(new RequestCulture(culture)),
            new CookieOptions { Expires = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddYears(1) });

        return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
    }
}
```

when I select english the variable `culture` contains `en` but the site always display the italian language.

What I missed?

**UPDATE**

This is actually the content of the variables for the `SelectLanguage` method:

[image]

as you can see the culture is passed correctly, after the execution of this method there is a refresh but instead of get the english language I get italian.

**UPDATE 2**

This is the operation flow that I did:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You shouldn't have to set `RequestCultureProviders` explicitly, try removing that. Also, can you post the controller's code?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I removed the `RequestCultureProviders` but same problem, I also added the full code of `LanguageController` in the question

Comment: I never used .net.core but I had a similar issue with .net. Is there a web.config in .net.core? If so, how is the <globalization> tag?

Comment: @GianpieroCaretti I'm learning `ASP.NET Core` so I'm not an expert at all, but I learned that we can store sensitive information using the `Secret Manager`: https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=windows or we can store a general configuration using the `appsettings.json` file

Comment: By th way, I solved a similar issue by not setting any locale in the server side configuration file. In .NET it is done via `<globalization>` tag in the web.config file. In .NET Core there'd be a similar cfg file: check if you have it, remove it and test again

Comment: No idea, meanwhile I added an image which contains the content of the variable for `SelectLanguage` method

Comment: What do you mean by **but the site always display the italian language.**? Could you share us a screen shot about the unexpected result and the expected result when using `http://localhost:5000/?culture=en`?

Comment: @TaoZhou Imagine that you select the English language from the drop down menu, after selecting it, the site reloads the page by internally calling the "SetLanguage" method on the "Language" controller, and passing the correct culture as a parameter. Now, instead of getting the site in English (ie the language you have selected), you get the same language as before (Italian) which is basically the default language, and this is obviously very strange.

Comment: It seems you want to access localized string in the view instead of controller, if so, you need to create localizer resource files in `views` folder instead of controller, check my answer.

Comment: solved by: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66411764/187650

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your current settings, you will need to do like below:

```
    public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IStringLocalizer<HomeController> _localizer;
    public HomeController(IStringLocalizer<HomeController> localizer)
    {
        _localizer = localizer;
    }
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewData["Title"] = _localizer["Title"];//"Your application description page.";
        return View();
    }
```

And then, use `ViewData["Title"]` in the view to access the licalizered content.

If you want to access localizer like below in the view:

```
@inject IViewLocalizer Localizer
<label>@Localizer["Title"]</label>
```

You need to create View localizer like below:

[image]

Comment: I'm so confused now for the following reason: I created two `.resx` files, one for `italian` language and another for `english` language. The `italian` language works perfectly, so if it as you said the software could not load the localized `italian` string, and should have return the `key` setted on the `Localizer` declared as `@inject IStringLocalizer<AccountController> Localizer`. So I don't understand why this won't work when I select the `english` language

Comment: @Charanoglu Not sure what you mean by one works, and another not, is there any screen shot? Can you reproduce your issue with [this](https://github.com/Edward-Zhou/AspNetCore/tree/master/LocalizationPro)? And share us the detail steps.

Comment: I added some images that explain better the problem. I'm cheking your repo

Comment: Is `@Localizer["Language"]` in `_SelectLanguagepartial.cshtml` or `AccountController View`? For `_SelectLanguagepartial.cshtml`, if you did not add `Views.Shared._SelectLanguagePartial.en.resx` , I am confused that you could get `italian` string.

Comment: The `@Localizer["Language"]` is inside `AccountController View`, the funny thing is that I implemented my code in your solution and for you works, no way.

Comment: @Charanoglu Could you share us your project to reproduce your issue?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179165/discussion-between-charanoglu-and-tao-zhou).

Comment: I added an answer and I found the problem, but I don't understand why the code block cause this, could you take a look?

Comment: could I ask you a question in the chat room?

Comment: @Charanoglu It seems to be related with **A cookie consent feature allows you to ask for (and track) consent from your users for storing personal information. If a user hasn't consented to data collection and the app has CheckConsentNeeded set to true, non-essential cookies aren't sent to the browser.**, check [EU General Data Protection Regulation (GDPR) support in ASP.NET Core](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/gdpr?view=aspnetcore-2.1). You may try [Essential cookies](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/gdpr?view=aspnetcore-2.1#essential-cookies)

Comment: ok, I understood but I need to ask you a question in chat if you have time, I'm waiting in the chat room

Answer (score 1):

Never though a similar thing, as I said I' not an `ASP.NET Core` expert, and I'm currently learning it, but the problem is not caused by the code posted in my question but is caused by this:

```
services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
{
   // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
   options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
   options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
});
```

The "bug" is on the line: `options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;`

I don't know why this prevent to `Append` a `Cookie` which is in this case related to the language, maybe this is a bug? Anyway, I commented this line of code, but if someone could provide an explaination for this I'll be glad.

Comment: Did u ever fix this I am facing the issue